# Chapter 1 appears instead of chapter 2 in the heading line :/

Tags: sectioning

[image][image]

This is supposed to be chapter 2 but it appears as chapter 1! Please help :(

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You forgot to include the image.  Also you should include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for us to reproduce your error.  Furthermore your questions does not make much sense.  It is supposed to show »Chapter 2« and it shows »Chapter 2«?  What is the problem?  I'm voting to close as unclear for now.  Ping me for reopening.

Comment: I'm new to this, my problem is that this is chapter 2 when the heading says chapter 1 as you can see in my picture now

Comment: your picture only show, that your chapter 1 is mentioned twice ... we can't help you without to see (minimal version of) your document.

Comment: The question will probably be closed. We can not do much for you. Maybe you just need to compile twice or change the commands about the headings. Impossible to say without MWE.